# kubernetes Init Container - can we run it conditionally?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, init

I had a requirement wherein we need to support backward compatibility.

- Old implementation is we are fetching credentials thru init container
- new implementation, we will fetch credentials thru credentials request.

With the new implementation, there's no need to run init-container anymore, but still we wanted to support backward compatibility wherein customer can have an option to still use the old implementation.

Is it possible for kubernetes init-container to run it conditionally by just providing flag in the deployment file?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

1. Use Helm and set a conditional clause around the init container block and you set the flag via the chart values.yaml or as a command line `--set` argument
2. Run the init container all the time, but pass an environment variable into it as well to indicates whether it should pull credentials. If it's set to pull credentials, it'll do so, if it is not set, it'll terminate and do nothing.

Comment: THanks for the idea, I will try to look on these then will update the thread.